# Subaru starting problem

Tags: starter

My 1990 Subaru Legacy wont start, it started it a week ago and it idled for 5 minutesthen sudently it stopped and cannot again.  Kindly assist me to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide us with more information? Has the engine not been running for a week? I have a feeling that there isn't any gas being pumped to the engine. What happens when you turn the key? Is it not igniting? etc..

Comment: How many miles on the car? When was the timing belt last changed? Do you have any compression?

Answer (score -3):

For me I can say check the fuel system of that vehicle and also spurk plugs to see if there is spurks

Comment: Spark plugs and sparks...